# Django cron for fetching RSS

Tags: python, django, rss, cron

I am new to Django, Python and Web Development and am trying to make an RSS reader as a learning project. Now, I need help with implementing the part of regularly checking up on all channels for new content (like say every 15 mins.). I need a cron job for this and custom management commands are the way to go about it, I know that much. But I am struggling to figure out how to implement that. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) link is what most people are recommending on SO, but I did not find it very helpful, like for instance, I does not explain about the scheduling for X amount of time part.

Can someone please explain, through code, how to implement checking up on channels for new content every 15 mins. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "every 15 minutes" bit is the easiest actually. Once you have written the command to check it *once*, you set up cron to execute the command every 15 minutes.

[This article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) has a quick overview of cron in general and how to set it up.

Things to keep in mind when running cron:

1. Cron processes run under their own shell (typically `/bin/sh`) and as such do not have access to all your customizations (such as things you have added to your `PATH`).
2. This also means that you need to provide the *full path* to any executable that you need to run. For example, don't type `python`, but rather `/usr/bin/python`, or whatever is applicable to your system.
3. The results of cron tasks are typically emailed to your system user account. You can check these messages by installing a mail reader. [`mutt`](http://www.mutt.org) is my favorite console email reader.  You can set the variable `MAILTO` in your cron file if you want to redirect cron results to your email.
4. Also, keep in mind that common [bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) like the `source` command won't work in cron.

Once you have your management command written; just add it to your own crontab file. This file lists all the command that the system-wide cron process will execute.

To edit your crontab file, type `crontab -e` from a console.

Each line in the file that isn't a comment is an entry. Entries start with the frequency, then the command to run. Here is the general format:

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or use names)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

An asterisk `*` in any position means "all".

To run something every 15 minutes:

```
0/15**** /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/project/manage.py foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future refs to this, the frequency params are separated by spaces (maybe they have got lost in the posting). A good place to try out various combinations is www.dataphyx.com/cronsandbox/.